# "what" as a determiner

Tags: sentence-patterns, determiners

I am composing a sentence describing results of an experiment:

> we find [results] beyond what can be expected from [theory]

I am not sure this is a proper use of "what". Does my sentence needs rewording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a correct use of it in the sense given [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/what_2) where it means "that which".

Some people might prefer "that which" as more formal, but others would prefer "what" so you can certainly stay with it.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean 'what can be expected from theory X is Y. These results go beyond Y.'

If this assumption is correct, I suggest 'we find that (results) go beyond the results which can be expected from (theory).'

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I was trying to avoid the use of a placeholder word like "the  results" in your sentence. Is there a way to connect (results) directly to (expectations) which are exceeded?

Comment: @slaviks There's a good document on strategies for academic writing for ESL speakers at www.helsinki.fi/kksc/language.services/AcadWrit.pdf